# Placing the bootstrap components in line

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I work on a Bootstrap HTML page and I would like to place a search field and button inline right side of the `BOOKS` drop-down menu.

[image]

However, with using the code, the search button goes below of the search field. The code is provided,

```
<div id="navbar">

                <!-- left components of the navbar -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">


                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                        aria-expanded="false">BOOKS <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                            <li><a href="#">BROWSE THE BOOKSELF</a></li>

                            <li class="divider" role="separator"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">STORE HOURS &amp; DIRECTIONS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <!-- book search -->
                    <form class="navbar-form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="keyword" placeholder="Book Search">  
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">SEARCH</button>
                    </form>


                </ul>

                <!-- right components of the navbar -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">SHOPPING CART</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MY ACCOUNT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">LOGOUT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- navbar div -->
```

This is how it looks like after using the code,

[image]

How do I put the **SEARCH button** right side of the input field?

`UPDATE`

If I put the `<button>` inside the `<div>` tag, it looks like the following overall and not desirable as well.

```
            <!-- book search -->
            <form class="navbar-form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="keyword" placeholder="Book Search">  
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">SEARCH</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `inline-flex`

```
.navbar-form{
  display:inline-flex;
}
```

Complete [guide of flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: Do you happen to know if this is an issue to mix up the Bootstrap and the Flexbox?

Comment: flexbox is more of a layout how the contents appear.

Answer (score 0):

```html
                    <!-- book search -->
                    <form class="navbar-form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="keyword" placeholder="Book Search">  
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">SEARCH</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Works.. You had put the  outside the DIV tag.